# Handle thousands of socket message in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, socket.io

I am working on a code where I need to display socket messages in the tableview and tableview get scroll to bottom with slow animation. I handle that but if the message load from socket is continues (consider 20/30 message per second) then the UI get freeze. I need to show the message like Facebook do on live screen one or two messages per iteration.

Here is my code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.025, target: self, selector: #selector(self.scrollTableView(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        self.designLayout()

    }

@objc func scrollTableView(_ timer: Timer) {

        guard messagesData.count > 0 else {
            return
        }
        if tableView.contentSize.height > tableView.bounds.height {
            tableView.contentInset.top = 0
        }
        tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: messagesData.count - 1, section: 0), at: UITableViewScrollPosition.bottom, animated: true)

    }
self.socket.on(“key”) {data, ack in
                print("data type is \(type(of: data))")
                let arrayValue = data as Array<Any>
                DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                    self.handleCountsAndMessaging(data: arrayValue)
                }
            }

func handleCountsAndMessaging(data: Array<Any>) {
  if let arrData = data[0] as? NSMutableDictionary {
     if(arrData.object(forKey: "text") != nil) {
                self.tableDataLoading(str: String(describing: arrData.object(forKey: "text")!))
            }
     }
}

func tableDataLoading() {
    print ("sttttttt \(str)")
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.messagesData.add(str)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Some times I get messages like 200 at time from socket and again 200 while processing previous messages, CPU consumption is showing like 120 and UI get freeze.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is 'live' and 'live':) 
This a phone we are talking about, so it's useless to update the screen every 0.025 seconds... you can easily slow down your fetch time but let's work one problem at a time :

1/ Don't use tableView.scrollToRow, but rather 'insertRows(at indexPaths: [IndexPath], with animation: UITableViewRowAnimation)' to insert a new row, this way if your user is reading, something, he won't be disturbed if you add 200 new item
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614879-insertrows

2/ Slow down your UI updates, you are overusing your main thread... You can fetch every 25ms if you like, but I recommend using a throttling mechanism to update the UI only if you get new content, and only if last UI update wasn't less than 5 seconds ago.

Comment: Thank you @Florian for guidance but still there is an issue about the load coming from socket, I’m maintaining only single array and once the messages are coming I’m updating the same array. How I hold socket data for mentioned time e.g 5 sec

Comment: What kind of issue?

Comment: sorry for late @Florian, the issue is about the time if I set update the table after 1 or 2 seconds it's not show smooth scrolling (like Facebook Live) and even I said ok for it, then also I face UI freeze issue when there is 400 messages coming from socket, I am worried if there 1000 people concurrency then how I am going to handle that?